# How to put an element between posts?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm developing an app that is similar to a blog and I need to put a different element (advertising) from the posts after three posts in every page. To explain better what I wanna do I'll try to illustrate:

```
[ POST ]
[ POST ]
[ POST ]
[ ELEMENT]
[ POST ]
[ POST ]
[ POST ]
[ ... ]
```

In every page I want to follow this pattern without interrupting the `for` cycle and without using any Javascript or CSS hack, just a server-side trick to do this.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Would it be possible to show some code and maybe elaborate on your question a little? Thank you! Based on what your question states now, I would assume you need to use a `layout`. See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#structuring-layouts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about using an index on your each, and the checking for the modulus ?

```
Posts.each_with_index do  |post,index| 
    [ Post _content_ here ]
   if index % 3 == 0
      [Element content here ] 
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly, I just had to change `%` with `==`

Comment: @FranBarros If the answer works, then consider marking it as the accepted answer for future viewers

Comment: well == will only do it when index is equal to 3, so if you had 9 items you would still only have 1 element.  I forgot the == 0 in my haste,  that will do it after every 3

Comment: I just wanted it to appear one time in every page. Just with `== 3` it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Gotcha, The question was a bit vague as to after 3, or every 3.